# 2D Textbox array causes early for loop exit

Tags: c#, arrays

I've been looking for a while and i couldn't find anything that would help me with my problem, but sorry if i missed something.

So for school we had to learn VB and make a game, and i chose to make Sudoku. I found VB easy to understand so i decided to try a different language to see if it was the same. C# was my choice. I decided to start off by making the Sudoku game again and compare it to my VB game.

In the VB code i was able to make an array of all the textboxes that make up the 9x9 grid from the code:

```
For Y = 0 to 8
    For X = 0 to 8

    Grid(X, Y) = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
        Pencil(X, Y) = New Windows.Forms.TextBox
        With Grid(X, Y)
            .BackColor = Grid(X, Y).BackColor
            .Name = Asc(97 + X) & Y + 1
            .Location = New System.Drawing.Point(35 + 50 * X + (FindBox(X) - 1) * 15, 50 + 50 * Y + (FindBox(Y) - 1) * 15)
            .Size = New System.Drawing.Size(50, 50)
            .Multiline = True
            .MaxLength = 1
            .Font = New Font(Grid(X, Y).Font.Name, Grid(X, Y).Font.Size + 10)
            .TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Center
            .TabIndex = (X + 1) + (Y * 9) + 1
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(Grid(X, Y))
    next
next
```

This meant i could easily refer to the Sudoku textbox's as a grid coordinate in the array. I attempted to replicate this in C# and ran into a problem almost instantly

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TextBox[,] Grid = new TextBox[8,8];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int Y = 0; Y < 9; Y++)
        {
            for (int X = 0; X < 9; X++)
            {
                TextBox TBox = new TextBox();
                Grid[X, Y] = TBox;
                TBox.Location = new Point(50 + X * 100, 50 + Y * 50);
                this.Controls.Add(TBox);
            }
        }
    }
```

This code runs, but for some reason it only runs till Y = 7, then stops and does not loop any more times. This code works fine until i try to add anything that links the textbox's to the array (In this case Grid[X,Y] = TBox). I've tried it without using TBox (And just straight away using the array, but the same problem persists).

Just wondering if anyone can enlighten me as to why adding the line "Grid[X, Y] = TBox;" can completely ruin a nested for loop.

Thanks in advance, sorry if i didn't say enough/Said too much.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops running"? Does it mean that an exception was thrown? Could you show how you initialized Grid field/variable?

Comment: Sorry i thought i copied all of it.

What i mean by Stops running it just that. It doesn't give me any errors, it just doesn't run it for the 8th time, and doesn't run the first for loop more than once.

I made a list box that displays the X and Y values for each itteration and all it shows is:


(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0), (6,0), (7,0). Where as if i get rid of that 1 line, it continues for all values of X and Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't just stop.You get a IndexOutOfRangeException
Change this

```
new TextBox[8,8]
```

to this

```
new TextBox[9,9]
```

Or make the for loops  "< 8"

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I feel quite stupid now, such a simple solution. Does that mean that Array[9] means that is can store 9 values? Rather than Vb's method, where Array(8) means it can store 9 different values.

Comment: You're welcome.It was not a stupid question but you should have noticed the exception.Yes C# arrays are different from VB arrays as Michal Komorowski said

Comment: I only just now read about Try Catch's, Are they the only way to get errors in C# (I wasn't getting an error while running my code before)? I thought they were a suggestion not a necessity while coding? I guess that's just another difference in the languages. Again thank you, and Michal for taking your time to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference between C# and VB.NET in the context of arrays. Just a simple example. In C# the following array has exactly 10 elements and allowed indexes are from 0 to 9:

```
int[] array= new int[10];
```

In VB.NET the following array has 11 elements and allowed indexes are from 0 to 10:

```
Dim array(10) as Integer
```

You translated you code from VB.NET to C# without taking this difference into account and it is why you have problems. To fix this problem you should use:

```
TextBox[,] Grid = new TextBox[9,9];
```

Instead of:

```
TextBox[,] Grid = new TextBox[8,8];
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm an idiot for trying to quickly go over the 'basics' of the programming language. When i was reading about C# arrays i read that they also go from 0 to the max index, so i foolishly assumed that it was declared the same way.